# Showing $A \subset B \iff A\cap B=A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Showing

$A \subset B \iff A\cap B=A$

How would I show this?

**My proof**

Assume

i. $A \cap B \subset A$

ii.$A \subset A \cap B$

Let $x$ be any element.

Assume $x \in A \cap B$. Then $x \in A$ and $ x \in B$. By hypthesis $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$ Thus $x \in A$

ii.

Let $ x \in A$ By hypthesis $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$

thus $x \in A \cap B$.

**Part 2**

$ A\cap B=A \rightarrow A \subset B$

But I find myself stuck here.

Comment: You should read Ivo Terek's answer very carefully, it is a very good explanation of how you should approach this sort of proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is a cleaner way to write it. We want to prove $A \subset B \iff A \cap B  = A$

**i)** $A \subset B \implies A \cap B = A$

Here, we have to prove a set equality, so we have to prove both inclusions, assuming that $A \subset B$. First, let's prove that $A \cap B \subset A$. Let $x \in A \cap B$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Well, $x \in A$, and we have $A \cap B \subset A$.

Now, we must get the other inclusion, $A \subset A \cap B$. Let $x \in A$. Since $A \subset B$, we have $x \in B$. But $x \in A$ *and* $x \in B$ means that $x \in A \cap B$, hence $A \subset A \cap B$.

Both inclusions give $A  = A \cap B$.

**ii)** $A \cap B = A \implies A \subset B$

Now, forget everything we've done until now. Assume that $A \cap B = A$, and we will prove that $A \subset B$. Let $x \in A$. That means, by hypothesis, that $x \in A \cap B$. So, $x \in B$, also, and we got $A \subset B \qquad\square$.

Notice where exactly I used every hypothesis, and the structure of the proof. If you still have any doubts, please say.

Comment: It is not necessary to use the assumption that $A \subset B$ in order to show that $A \cap B \subset A$.  Once we know that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, it follows immediately that $x \in A$.

Comment: This is a reasonably clear and brief explanation of a mathematician's methodical approach to such a proof. OP should read and understand your explanation, it is quite instructive an should serve him well. Nice. +1.

Comment: thanks this makes me understand how you use the hypothesis to help justify your conclusion

Answer (score 2):

If $A \cap B = A$, then this means that for all $a\in A$, we have both $a \in A$ and $a \in B$ (definition of being in an intersection).

Answer (score 1):

What you have written seems correct, but a bit confusing.

I might write the proof like this

**Proof**

We want to prove that 
$$
A \subset B \iff A\cap B=A
$$
Assume that the right hand side is true. That is, assume that $A\cap B = A$. We want to show that $A\subseteq B$. Let $a\in A$. Since $A = A\cap B$, we have $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Hence $A\subseteq B$.

Assume now that the left hand side is true. That is, assume that $A\subseteq B$. We want to prove that $A\cap B = A$. We do this by proving to inclusions

1. $A\cap B \subseteq A$ and
2. $A\subseteq A\cap B$.

To show 1. let $x\in A\cap B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Hence $A\cap B \subseteq A$.

To how 2. let $x\in A$. Then since $A\subseteq B$ we have $x\in B$. So $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Then by definition of intersection $x\in A\cap B$.

$\square$

Answer (score 1):

- If $A \subset B$, then for every $a \in A$, we have $a \in B$ by definition of "$\subset$", thus $a \in A \cap B$. This shows that $A \subset A \cap B$. Now if $a \in A \cap B$ then $a \in A$ by definition of "$\cap$" and thus $A \cap B \subset A$. It follows that $A = A \cap B$.
- If $A \cap B = A$, then for every $a \in A$,  we have $a \in A \cap B$ by definition of "$=$" and thus $a \in B$ by definition of "$\cap$". This shows that $A \subset B$.