# For all sets A and B, if A ⊆ B, then A ∪ B ⊆ B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve a proof,  but I'm a little lost on how to structure it.  I have the following setup, but I'm not sure what to put in most of the blank spaces.

**Proposition:** For all sets A and B, if A ⊆ B, then A ∪ B ⊆ B

**Proof:** Suppose A and B are any sets and A ⊆ B. We must show that _.  Let x ∈ _.  We must show that _.  By definition of union, x ∈ _ _ x ∈ _.  In case x ∈ _ then since A ⊆ B, x ∈ _.  In case x ∈ B, then clearly x ∈ B.  So in either case, x ∈ _ as was to be show.

The best guesses I've made are as follows:

**Proof:** Suppose A and B are any sets and A ⊆ B. We must show that **A ∪ B ⊆ B**.  Let x ∈ **A**.  We must show that _.  By definition of union, x ∈ _ _ x ∈ _.  In case x ∈ **A** then since A ⊆ B, x ∈ **B**.  In case x ∈ B, then clearly x ∈ B.  So in either case, x ∈ **A ∪ B ⊆ B** as was to be show.

I didn't bother filling in the blanks in the middle as I'm pretty lost on what should go into those.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: To prove that $A \cup B \subseteq B$, you need to take any element of $A \cup B$ and show that it *must* belong to $B$.

Comment: I know what the answer is, I just have to set it up in the above format, and I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: You're thinking about this wrong if you're trying to guess what goes in blanks. Sit down and think about what this statement means

Comment: see my answer to [**this question**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273782/show-that-a-cap-b-b-iff-a-cup-b-a-where-a-subseteq-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are any sets and $A \subseteq B.$ We must show that $ x\in A\cup B \implies x\in B$.  Let $x \in A\cup B$.  We must show that $x\in B$.  By definition of union, $x \in A$ or $x\in B$.  In case $x\in A$ then since $A\subseteq B$ $x\in B$.  In case x ∈ B, then clearly x ∈ B.  So in either case, $x\in B$ as was to be show.