# Proving that $A\subset B$ if given $A=A\cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = A \cap B$. Prove $A \subseteq B$

I go about like this :

Let $x \in (A \cup B)$

$\implies x\in A ~~\text{and} ~~ x\in B$

**Question 1 :** Is this true? Will **and** come here? Ideally **or** should come, as it is a union.

**Question 2 :** How should we prove this ideally? Is there any better beginning? Our teacher said to use Venn diagrams, but I want to prove it in writing.

Comment: Using a Venn diagram is not the way to *prove* something

Comment: @MagicMan but a Venn diagram should lead to a proper proof.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Sure, but I don't think anyone in their right mind would say hey look at this Venn diagram! It's proof! I hope the teacher isn't suggesting a Venn diagram is a proof. That would make me sad, but it wouldn't really be too terribly surprising.

Comment: The teacher might well have said "draw a Venn Diagram"... a perfectly reasonable way to understanding and a proper proof.

Comment: Teacher said to use venn diagram as proof.

Comment: A Venn diagram is a bizarre way of trying to 'prove' (well, demonstrate) this result. Just use the fact that $A\cap B\subset B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $A=A\cap B$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cap B$; that is, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Since $x\in B$, we necessarily have that $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: you were the first one so tick

Answer (score 4):

Definition: $A\subseteq B\iff (x\in A\,\Rightarrow\, x\in B)$

In this case: $(x\in A=A\cap B\,\Rightarrow\, x\in B)$, so $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 2):

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal iff $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$ simultaneously. So, if $x \in A$, since $A \subset A \cap B$, we have that $ x \in A \cap B,$ that is, $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. It follows that every $x \in A$ also belongs to $B$, so $A \subset B$.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/841024/showing-a-subset-b-iff-a-cap-b-a?lq=1), there are 4 answer for more general case $A \subseteq B \iff A\cap B=A$. And [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273782/show-that-a-cap-b-b-iff-a-cup-b-a-where-a-subseteq-b), I have more: $A\cap B=A\iff A\subseteq B$$\color{red}{\iff A\cup B=B}.$